# Why can't I have a duplicate case in my switch statement?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I understand that this will fail to compile:

```
int caseNum = 2;

switch(caseNum)
{
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Happy");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Birthday");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("To the ground!");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("<3");
        break;
}
```

I know that the case statements are conflicting and that the compiler "doesn't know which 'case 2' I am talking about".  A few peers of mine and myself were wondering behind the scenes what the conflict is and had heard that switch statements are converted into hash-maps.  Is that the case, does a switch statement become a hash-map during compile time and the conflict in the mapping create the error?

So far I have looked around Stack Overflow and Google for an answer, and the information must be out there already, but I am unsure how to express the question correctly it would appear.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have two cases with the same value because you could put the code of both in one case. The implementation details are not the cause, it is just how this construct language was made.

Comment: As stated, I'm aware of that, I am wondering what the implementation of a switch statement is behind the scenes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A hash map is just one way that a switch statement could be compiled, but in any case, you can imagine having duplicate `case`s as trying to have multiple values for the same key in a regular `HashMap`. The compiler doesn't know which one of the values corresponds to the key, and so emits an error.

`switch` statements could also be compiled into a jump table, in which case this is still ambiguous for a very similar reason -- you have multiple different possibilities for the same jump location.

`switch` statements could also be compiled into a binary search, in which case you still have the same problem -- multiple different results for the same key being searched for.

---

Just in case you were curious, I did a small test case to see what `javac` would compile the `switch` to. From this (slightly modified) source:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final int caseNum = 2;

    switch (caseNum) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Happy");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Birthday");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("To the ground!");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("<3");
            break;
    }
}
```

You get this bytecode:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_2      
       1: tableswitch   { // 1 to 3
                     1: 28
                     2: 39
                     3: 50
               default: 61
          }
      28: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      31: ldc           #3                  // String Happy
      33: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      36: goto          69
      39: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      42: ldc           #5                  // String Birthday
      44: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      47: goto          69
      50: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      53: ldc           #6                  // String To the ground!
      55: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      58: goto          69
      61: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      64: ldc           #7                  // String <3
      66: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      69: return
```

So at least for this small `switch`, a jump table seems to be used. I have heard that the way switches are compiled depends partly on their size, but I don't know the exact point at which the implementation changes. 20 cases still seem to be implemented as a jump table...

---

Turns out `String` switch statements are implemented a bit differently. From this source:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String caseNum = "2";

    switch (caseNum) {
        case "1":
            System.out.println("Happy");
            break;
        case "2":
            System.out.println("Birthday");
            break;
        case "3":
            System.out.println("To the ground!");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("<3");
            break;
    }
}
```

You get this bytecode:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String 2
       2: astore_2      
       3: iconst_m1     
       4: istore_3      
       5: aload_2       
       6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.hashCode:()I
       9: tableswitch   { // 49 to 51
                    49: 36
                    50: 50
                    51: 64
               default: 75
          }
      36: aload_2       
      37: ldc           #4                  // String 1
      39: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      42: ifeq          75
      45: iconst_0      
      46: istore_3      
      47: goto          75
      50: aload_2       
      51: ldc           #2                  // String 2
      53: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      56: ifeq          75
      59: iconst_1      
      60: istore_3      
      61: goto          75
      64: aload_2       
      65: ldc           #6                  // String 3
      67: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      70: ifeq          75
      73: iconst_2      
      74: istore_3      
      75: iload_3       
      76: tableswitch   { // 0 to 2
                     0: 104
                     1: 115
                     2: 126
               default: 137
          }
     104: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     107: ldc           #8                  // String Happy
     109: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     112: goto          145
     115: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     118: ldc           #10                 // String Birthday
     120: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     123: goto          145
     126: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     129: ldc           #11                 // String To the ground!
     131: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     134: goto          145
     137: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     140: ldc           #12                 // String <3
     142: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     145: return
```

So you still have jump tables, but you have two. Bit of a roundabout process -- take the hash code, switch on that, based on the case load another constant, and from that do a "normal" switch (I think). But same basic process, I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

Historically, `switch` statements were/could be implemented as jump tables (i.e. a mapping of value to destination address). Depending on the implementation of the table, it may be impossible to have two entries for the same value pointing to different addresses. Even if it were possible, how would you handle that duplicate value? Return from the first handler and then go to second handler? Never execute the second handler?

It makes no sense to allow this.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I could reword my question as 'why is ambiguity bad in programming?'  I am just wondering if switch statements are converted at compile time to something else before and besides the bytecode for the computer to read.